# Hide Google logo on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit, appstore-approval

Does somebody know how the Google logo can be hidden on a `MKMapView`?

I don't want to hide it. I want the opposite. The reason is that a app got rejected because of

> 8.6 Google Maps and Google Earth images obtained via the Google Maps API can be used within an application if all brand features of the original content remain unaltered and fully visible. Apps that cover up or modify the Google logo or copyright holders identification will be rejected

Now I want to undo this, but I don't know which code is responsible for this behavior.

**Edit:**

I think the reason is this code line

```
self.mapView=[[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
```

`self.view.bounds` does not take the navigation bar in account. I will try this:

```
CGRect mapSize = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 44.0f);
self.mapView = [[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:mapSize] autorelease];
```

Comment: When you launch your app, is the google logo hidden ? strange ^^ but I never tried to hide it.

Comment: I use the maps on two ways: One time I used a NIB and the other time not. When using the NIB I have the Google logo.

Comment: Nothing I can come up with will cause the map to resize programmatically.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Google logo automatically appears in the lower-left corner of any MapView. The only way it gets hidden is by covering that corner.

I haven't seen your app, but if I had to guess I'd say that one of these is true:

1. Your map view extends below a control near the bottom of the screen, like below a Tab Bar, or maybe just entirely off the bottom of the view if there's nothing down there (below 480 px on the iPhone).
2. Your map view is ok at the bottom except when something appears down there, like a Toolbar.
3. Things are generally laid out fine in portrait mode but when the user switches to landscape you're not resizing your map correctly and the bottom of it is getting cut off.

Comment: I select your answer as solution because you brought me on the idea to have a look at the borders of a view. The final solutions can be found in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have already made an application that was rejected because the logo was hidden by a translucent toolbar. Check that !

Answer (score 0):

When you get added to the UINavigationController, you should be getting auto-resized.

Have you set the springs + struts on your mapview to ensure it automatically shrinks to fit the space it's got available?

...more likely, have you ALSO set those on the parent view? If the parent view is failing to resize, and the map is taking the full size of the parent view, then the parent AND the map will both be off the bottom of the screen.

NB: if you do all this in Interface Builder, then it will auto setup most of these for you - but there are bugs in every version of IB, and it "fails" to set these correctly for certain UI elements, and in certain cases of nested views. Sometimes you have to fix it manually in IB, or in code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree, my apps that hid it have been accepted for ages and recent updates are rejecting it. Looks like they are clamping down